# Comprimir y descomprimir un directorio

Tags: python, zip

Estoy intentado comprimir de forma correct un directorio. El directorio tiene la siguiente forma:

```
Libro/Tipos/Recetas
```

En este sentido, `Libro` es el directorio maestro y contiene todas las subcarpetas `Tipos` y dentro de cada subcarpeta Tipo hay ficheros .txt que son las `Recetas`. He realizado lo siguiente:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('libro','zip',ruta_del_directorio_maestro)
```

Sin embargo, cuando descomprimo el archivo no me mantiene la estructura de carpetas. Solo muestra los archivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para preservar la estructura de directorios, tienes que indicar, además del `root_dir`, el `base_dir`, por ejemplo:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('libro','zip','/home/juan/libro', './')
```

O también:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('libro','zip','/home/juan/', 'libro/')
```

De acueerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive):

> `root_dir` is a directory that will be the root directory of the archive, all paths in the archive will be relative to it; for example, we typically chdir into root_dir before creating the archive.
>
> `base_dir` is the directory where we start archiving from; i.e. base_dir will be the common prefix of all files and directories in the archive. base_dir must be given relative to root_dir.

Mi traducción libre sería:

> `root_dir` es un directorio que será el directorio raíz del archivo, todas las rutas del archivo serán relativas a él; por ejemplo, normalmente usamos `chdir` en `root_dir` antes de crear el archivo.
>
> `base_dir` es el directorio desde donde comenzamos a archivar; es decir, `base_dir` será el prefijo común de todos los archivos y directorios del archivo. La ruta de `base_dir` proporcionarse relativa a `root_dir`.

La documentación contiene un [ejemplo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil-archiving-example-with-basedir) que quizás te termine de aclarar.